# HTML5 Android Notification, (Intel XDK?)

Tags: java, android, html, notifications, push-notification

(When I say "App" I am only talking about Android, I'm not gonna even try to deal with Apple)

So I have a website that I'd like to develop an Android app for. All I need it to do is show the website(it'll change some styling if being accessed from the app), which I can do just fine.

I use Intel XDK, which works great. But the notification options it offers seems to be just mass-notification stuff, not individualized.

All I want to do is be able to tell users when they get a notification from my website(like a message from another user).

I've looked all over the place for hours and hours and can't find anything useful. There are a ton of extremely complicated Java codes and tutorials, but I don't even know Java. I'm solely a web developer and all I want is an app that makes it easier for users to check the website.

I'm hoping there is some Java file out there that I can send data to somehow that will allow me to create and delete push notifications on Android systems. Maybe a HTML5 library or JS function, I dunno.

I simply can't seem to implement it myself, and I'm definitely not going to learn an entire dying language just for one basic thing that should be simple to do. Anything you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated. Optimally I would like to get a Java file I can download and put into my app that gives a notification, then I can edit it to say what I need it to or whatever(I also would really like a way to make the notification go away[in case the user sees it on another device before seeing it on the phone] ). I would also need to know how to call onto this Java file, make it check for notifications on the server or whatever.

I know this is all very nooby stuff, but I run an independent website and simply don't have the time to learn all this stuff when my needs are so basic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you can tell I've become quite frustrated with this. It should be way simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use appMobi for push messaging, see documentation at http://docs.appmobi.com/index.php/push-messages/pushjsapi/. You can setup your appMobi account in the Services tab of the Intel XDK.

```
//Check if user is registered
var onDeviceReady=function() {
    //See if the push user exists already
    //You can send any unique user id and password.
    AppMobi.notification.checkPushUser(AppMobi.device.uuid, AppMobi.device.uuid);
};
document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);


//if user is not registered, register them
var isUserAdded = false;
var notificationsRegistered=function(event) {
    if(event.success === false) {
        if (!isUserAdded) {
            isUserAdded= true;
            AppMobi.notification.addPushUser(AppMobi.device.uuid, 
                                              AppMobi.device.uuid, 
                                             'no@email.com');
            return;
        }
        AppMobi.notification.alert("Notifications Failed: " + event.message,
                                   "My Message","OK");
        return;
    }
    var msg = event.message || 'success';
   AppMobi.notification.alert("Notifications Enabled: " + msg,
                              "My Message","OK");
};
document.addEventListener("appMobi.notification.push.enable",
                           notificationsRegistered,false);

//when push message event is found get notification
var receivedPush = function(){
    var myNotifications=AppMobi.notification.getNotificationList();
    //It may contain more than one message, so iterate over them
    var len=myNotifications.length;
    if(len > 0) {
        for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
            msgObj=AppMobi.notification.getNotificationData(myNotifications[i]);
            try{
                if(typeof msgObj == "object" && msgObj.id == myNotifications[i]){
                    AppMobi.notification.alert(msgObj.msg + "\n" + msgObj.data 
                     + "\n" + msgObj.userkey,"pushMobi Message","OK");
                    //Always delete messages after they are shown 
                    AppMobi.notification.deletePushNotifications(msgObj.id);
                    return;
                }
                AppMobi.notification.alert("Invalid Message Object: " + i,
                                           "My Message","OK");
            }catch(e){
                AppMobi.notification.alert("Caught Exception For: " + msgObj.id,
                                           "My Message","OK");
                AppMobi.notification.deletePushNotifications(msgObj.id);
            }
        }
    }
};
document.addEventListener("appMobi.notification.push.receive", receivedPush, false);


//send a push notification from your website
AppMobi.notification.sendPushNotification(myAppMobiUserID,"new website blog posted!",{});
document.addEventListener("appMobi.notification.push.send",updateNotificationEvent,false);
var updateNotificationEvent=function(event)
{
    if(event.success==false)
{
    alert("error: " + event.message)
}
    else
    {
        alert("success");
    }
}
```

You can also use Parse.com APIs but I don't believe the subscribe to channel JavaScript API is fully flushed out last I checked, see https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/JavaScript.

```
Parse.initialize("YOUR KEY", "HERE");

// Save the current Installation to Parse.
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

You can then send push notifications through the Web Console, or on your website using:

```
//The following code will push the alert to the "Winterhawks" and "Oil Kings" channels. 
Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [ "Winterhawks", "Oil Kings" ],
   data: {
      alert: "The Winterhawks won against the Oil Kings!"
   }
  }, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Subscribe to channels is not yet implemented for JavaScript as far as I know so you'll have to use REST or native APIs.